# change an exposed filter from a select box to a text field search

Tags: views

I have a view that utilizes a node-reference field. I want users to be able to filter by this field using a search-box (or an autocomplete field), but when I set the exposed filter to the node-reference field, all I get is a drop-down. How can I force this to be either a text field or autocomplete?

Thanks!

views 3
drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

This might help you,

http://drupal.org/node/506654#comment-6412784

[Views autocomplete filters](http://drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use entity reference instead of node reference. That module offers an autocomplete filter.